# How get input value in scriplet on jsp

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, scriptlet

I have html code:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
```

How can I get username's value in my scriplet ?

```
 <% String username= request.getParameter("username");
 %>
```

But it doesn't work for me 
How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you using form tag in your html? If not use it, place your input tag within it and put the name that of page in action attribute of form where you want to send input value. Isn't it very simple.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that `request`Object is only available when you send the `request`to the server or Submit the form .

- on Client side pass Some action inside form tag and mapped into XML file

  ```
  <form action="Submit.do">
  ```
- from server side like `servlet/Strtus/JSP` you can access `request`object using

  ```
  <% request.getParameter("inputid");%>
  ```
- if you calling Same page after Submitting the data then on scriptlet check for request object if it null then don't perform any action else get the object